# What command can I use to get filepath for a file alarm (using Yosemite/Mavericks)?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to find a way on how to attach an alarm on how to attach an file alarm on a calendar entry using Applescript and I'm getting this error:

```
Alerts that open files or scripts must include a file path
```

This is the code I'm running to attach the alarm

```
set startFile to "/Applications/TextEdit.app"
make new open file alarm at end with properties {trigger interval:-1, filepath:startFile}
```

So what I did is to create a file alarm manually and I want to view the file path to this alarm now via Applescript. I don't know how. I've looked at the dictionary on what command/function to use but I can't find it. Searching the net didn't give me answers either.

Can you please help? thanks

Comment: it sounds like all you need to do is provide the file path for the file that you want to attach the alarm to. So tell me how would you would determine what file you want attached to the alarm

Comment: can we see your script as well please, it may help us ,to help you if we have it

Comment: you say you want to attach a specific alarm file to a calendar entry, but you are scripting TextEdit. I don't understand.

Comment: the intention of the alarm is to open textedit once the alarm triggers

Comment: so is text edit your default text editor ?

Comment: also could you give us the ALL the relevant code please